# Office 365 Powershell authentication without storing credentials

Tags: powershell, office365, office365api

I want to provide some administrative services that will be implemented against the Office365 PowerShell, but I don't want to store decryptable administrators credentials - is there any option for authenticating without direct usage of the credentials? I am thinking about something like OAuth or another application key system.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear from the question but since you don't want to store creds I assume that this will be running on client computers rather than on systems that are directly under your control.  I can think of two options but they both add considerably to the complexity of a script like this.

**Option 1**

Split your script into 2 pieces, one set up as a web listener on a server that is running with elevated privileges and the other running on the system where you want the script to be placed that makes REST calls to your web listener, this lets you only expose the functions that you actually want the lower-privileged script to have access to without having to deal with storing the creds.  This is more complex to set up but doesn't require anything third-party to be in place.

**Option 2**

Use a privledged identity management system(I'm most familiar with CyberArk but any of them should be ok for this purpose) to store the creds, You would then sign your script with a certificate and set the identity manager to only allow a process signed with that cert and connecting from a known valid IP to access the credential, again using a web call. This is easier to do once you get the PIM installed but that can be a massive headache to do properly, not to mention expensive.

Hope I understood the problem correctly and that one of these methonds helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the application will run on systems that are under my control - but it will administrate Office365-instances for different users, so I wanted to avoid storing their personal admin credentials on my server. I think the right thing would be service credentials, but I don't think I can use them with PowerShell for Office365 - I opened a seperate question regarding this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097604/office-365-powershell-login-with-service-principal-or-oauth2