# office 365 powershell login with service principal or OAuth2

Tags: powershell, office365

I can find information about how to create Service Principals for Office365 with Powershell - but I can't find any how to login with them in Powershell. Is this not possible? I am currently using this code, that works with my Admin account but not with service credentials (that work with Azure) :

```
$AdminName = "application-id" 
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "application-key" -AsPlainText –Force

$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $Pass 

# Azure Login working
#$tenantId = "tenant-id"
#Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId


# MSOnline / Office365-Login not working
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
```

The error I get at the "Connect-MsolService" is :

> Connect-MsolService : Unable to authenticate your credentials. Make
>   sure that your user name is in the format: <username>@<domain>. If
>   this issue persists, contact Support.
>
> - Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80048862,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

Comment: Not working...can you show us the error output or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that - I added the error output now. It basically seems to be the Connect-MsolService-command not accepting app-ids as login-name.

Comment: Check if you are able to connect following this steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YgOT.png

Comment: The issues remain kind of the same - when I use my admin-credentials the login works, when I use the service principal credentials I get "New-PSSession : [ps.outlook.com] Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message :
[ClientAccessServer=***,BackEndServer=,RequestId=***,TimeStamp=12/12/2016
4:58:35 PM] Access Denied For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."